# Zend routes getting messed up

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, router

To begin with, I wanted to make it so when a user navigates to test.com/username it would take him to test.com/account/profile/name/username, so I added this route

```
    $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $fc->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':name',
            array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'profile'));

    $router->addRoute('profile',$route);
```

and it made it work, but now when I use the following link

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
                'controller' =>'account',
                'action'=>'update'), 'default',true);?>">Settings</a>
```

I guess it gets "confused" and uses the above route, since it doesn't go to test.com/account/update..

Do I have to add another route for the update action? Wouldn't that mean I would have to add a new route for all the actions associated with the account controller?

Any help here? :)

EDIT: What the issue is that the the link redirects to test.com/account/update, but it thinks that the "account" is the param defined in the route above (as in test.com/name), and not the controller so it redirects it to the 'profile' action.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what the issue is. Is the URL helper outputting the wrong lin, or is the link being output being matched by the wrong route? Or are you just unsure how to pass actions in to your profile route?

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated the post and I hope it is a bit clearer now..

Comment: So a request to /account/update is being matched by your profile route? As I don't see how a route with two params in could be matched by a route that has one. Are the routes definitely defined as in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url `/my-name` matches against the default route. Since:

1. The router attempts to match routes in the order they are specified, and
2. The default routes are added prior to your own named 'profile' route

the 'default' route is the one that gets used.

The solution is to have your routes defined starting from most-specific to most-general.

So, in your case, I would try (during bootstrap) removing the default routes, adding your named 'profile' route, and then adding back the default routes.

As a side note: With the 'profile' route as you have defined it, if you want to have urls for static pages like `/contact`, `/about`, etc, these will have to use custom routes defined *before* your 'profile' route, so that the 'profile' route doesn't get a chance to match against them and redirect.

**Update**

As @TimFountain reminded me below, routes are matched in *reverse-order*, so my specific recommendation above isn't actually right. But apparently order was the issue.

Comment: Actually routes are matched in reverse order, so your highest priority routes should be defined last

Comment: The order was important, I didn't really know that. Thanks David and Tim, actually yes they are matched in reverse order, so since I changed it up a bit, everything works fine.

Comment: Yikes! I can't believe I got that one wrong. Thanks for the correction, @TimFountain. Removing my answer since it's, well, wrong.